# Text box hiding behind image in libre office draw

Tags: libreoffice

I am using libre office draw in ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to put in text boxes at the right position. However, the text box seems to be hiding behind the image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the image -> arrange --> send to back